# Apagar valor do file com a informação que vem do banco de dados

Tags: jquery

Tenho um formulário de cadastro onde entre os campos tem um campo file. Ele cadastra normalmente.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="foto">Foto do(a) Vereador(a):</label>
    <input type="file" name="Foto" class="form-control" id="fileUpload" placeholder="Foto do Vereador(a)">
    <img id="imagem" src="#" alt="Preview da sua imagem" style="width: 130px; margin-top: 10px; display: none" class="img-thumbnail" />
    <label id="excluir" style="margin-left: 50px; color: #00F; display: none; cursor: pointer">Excluir</label>
 </div>
```

**JQuery**

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $("#imagem").attr('src', e.target.result);           
        }     
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);         
    }
}

$("#fileUpload").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
    $("#imagem").css("display","block");
    $("#excluir").css("display","block");
});

$("#excluir").click(function(){
    $("#fileUpload").val("");
    $("#imagem").css("display","none");
    $("#excluir").css("display","none");
});
```

Tudo bem, tudo certo! O único problema é quando tento trazer esse campo na edição do usuário. Na hora de trazer os resultados do banco de dados para a edição estou fazendo dessa forma:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="foto">Foto do(a) Vereador(a):</label>
    <input type="file" name="Foto" class="form-control" id="fileUpload" value="<?php echo $visualizar->FotoUsuario; ?>">
    <img id="imagem" src="<?php echo "../../fotos/".$visualizar->FotoUsuario; ?>" alt="Preview da sua imagem" style="width: 130px; margin-top: 10px;" class="img-thumbnail" /><br>
    <label id="excluir" style="margin-left: 50px; color: #00F; cursor: pointer">Excluir</label>
 </div>
```

O problema está quando clico no link Excluir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele não está apagando o value do campo file. O Jquery é o mesmo que passei mais acima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente fazer com attr:

```
$("#excluir").click(function(){
    $("#fileUpload").removeAttr("value");
    $("#imagem, #excluir").css("display","none");
});
```

Comment: Olá Lucas. Não funcionou. O nome da imagem continua no value do campo file.

Comment: Usa o removeAttr, tente agora

Comment: Obrigado Lucas.